# How to download public Google Drive file from Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, permission-denied

I have public Google Drive file like this one: https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B8G77eDgeMdwMmkwcnA5eUV2M0U&export=download

I want to download that file from a Chrome Extension.

I have added these urls to the "permissions" element in the extension manifest (there are some redirects when trying to download the file and I tried to add them all): "https://*.docs.googleusercontent.com/","https://docs.google.com/","http://docs.google.com/","https://accounts.google.com/", "https://www.google.com/"

When I try to download the file Chrome returns this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/nonceSigner?nonce=s35adai1lp052&continue=https://do…Ddownload%26h%3D16653014193614665626&hash=inkfclb76vcru6uuoqkfp274hk5joqk9. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It seems I have already allowed downloads for the url in question.

If I add the `<all_urls>` permission the download succeeds.

Any idea what permission I need to add? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to add a `*` to the end of your URLs (e.g., `https://www.google.com/*`). Your current permissions might only apply to those *exact URLs*, not any resource on those domains.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either, just tried it. I think Chrome just assumes that every url that starts with the requested persmission is allowed. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: One other possible idea: that URL might transparently perform a `301` or `302` redirect to a non-permitted origin. `<all_urls>` allows this hypothetical redirect (whatever it might be), but your list does not. Check your network logs in Dev Tools and see if (and where) that URL redirects.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the `https://www.google.com/` persmission. It's the redirect where Chrome returns an error. It redirects to here: `https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?REST_OF_URL_HERE` Thanks again.

Comment: Try `*.googleusercontent.com` instead of `*.docs.googleusercontent.com`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! Do you have any idea why that is? Also, do you want to submit that as an answer so I can accept it? :) Thanks again. This is how my permissions look now: "https://*.googleusercontent.com/","https://docs.google.com/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using for instance `wget` and looking at the reported redirections, you can see that the last host is something like:

`doc-0c-80-docs.googleusercontent.com`

The first part is probably variable, and wildcards in the host part of the URL can only match an entire part of the hostname. So you should add the following to your match patterns:

`*.googleusercontent.com`

Answer (score 1):

You need at least the following minimum to access Drive files:

- *://drive.google.com/*
- *://*.googleusercontent.com/*